# TSQL: Using replace function in select with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

**Background.** I'm using SQL Server. I have two tables in database:

```
Vendors(Id, Name, Description)
Products(Id, VendorId, Name, Description)
```

Values in `Id` column are formatted with prefix `'ID_'` in `Vendor` table.

Values in `VendorId` column are formatted with prefix `'VE_'` in `Products` table.

**E.g.** `'VE_001245'` in `Products` refers to `'ID_001245'` in `Vendors`.

(Please, do not propose to change this concept, do not care about database scheme, do not suggest adding foreign key. All it is just for illustration.)

**Question**: which one of following queries is best in performance context and why?

1. Use `replace` function in inner `select`:

   ```
   select v.* from Vendors v
   inner join
   (
       select distinct replace(VendorId, 'VE_', 'ID_') as Id
       from Products
   ) list
   on v.Id = list.Id
   ```
2. Use `replace` function in `on`-statement:

   ```
   select v.* from Vendors v
   inner join
   (
       select distinct VendorId as Id
       from Products
   ) list
   on v.Id = replace(list.Id, 'VE_', 'ID_')
   ```

**Edit.** There is only clustered index in each table (by `Id` column). Each table can contains millions rows.

Comment: My guess would be 2, as with 1) I have to run the function over the entire list of Products, then select the distinct from that. With the second, I only run the function on a distinct list (i.e. the amount of rows I have to run replace on should be smaller). Hard to know though, without knowing what the data numbers are, indexes, and so on. Since you have access to the schema, why not run both with the Actual Execution Plan showing and compare results?

Comment: Can you add [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.90).aspx) (SQL2005+) ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: No, I cannot modify DB scheme.

Comment: @dash I've updated question with details about indices and estimated table sizes. Currently table are not filled. So I fear that Actual Execution Plan will be changed when tables will be filled.

Answer (score 0):

Both the queries are almost same in terms of performance. In the first query **sorting** is done twice, once when you are selecting the distinct records and again when it is performing an inner join, and in the end a **merge join** is there to select the final result set.
Whereas in second query sorting is done only once but **Hash join** is being performed which is more expensive then merge join.
So both the queries are same performance wise in the scenario when you don't have any index on the table.

Comment: There is only clustered index in each table (by Id column).

Comment: In that case depending upon the amount of that you can select the queries. The first query is using Nested loop join which is good when the data is less, and second query is using merge join which works well with the large amount of data.