# Select replace and then join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I want to combine.

The first table has a key record column `ITEMID` where the key records have the suffix `ITEMID_CV`, and the table contains one other column of data that I want. The second table has the same key record but with a different suffix `ITEMID_PH` and the rest of the columns of data.

For the first table, I can use:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE (ITEMID,'CV','PH') AS ITEMID, 
    CAST (ENDDATE AS DATETIME) AS ENDDATE 
FROM PLTReports
```

Which gives me the `ITEMID` name that is the same as the second table. So I'm partway there. Now what I don't know how to do is to join this result onto the rest of the other table. The following gives me an ambiguous column name error. The error is: 
Error --------------------

> Unable to link to external table: Unexpected Server Error: 'Deferred
>   prepare could not be completed. Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>   Ambiguous column name 'ITEMID'.'.  Use Event Viewer to see the PI AF
>   Server log file for more information.

I think I might be close to solving this, but can't really find an example of how to do it, and I've probably used the wrong syntax.

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE (ITEMID,'CV','PH') AS ITEMID, 
    CAST (ENDDATE AS DATETIME) AS ENDDATE 
FROM PLTReports 
INNER JOIN PRODUCTION_ALL ON PRODUCTION_ALL.ITEMID = PLTReports.ITEMID
```

Does anyone have a strategy on how to do this? It's probably simple but I'm just not quite getting there.

Edit: This is for creating a linked table in PI AF, I can't recall offhand what flavor of SQL it uses.

Comment: REPLACE (PLTReports.ITEMID,'CV','PH') AS ITEMID,

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: It seems to be Sql Server : https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Products/PI-Server/PI-AF/System-Requirements

Comment: The error you get is with wich *exact* query ?

Answer (score 1):

You almost had the solution :

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE (ITEMID,'CV','PH') AS ITEMID, 
    CAST (ENDDATE AS DATETIME) AS ENDDATE 
FROM PLTReports 
INNER JOIN PRODUCTION_ALL 
    ON PRODUCTION_ALL.ITEMID = REPLACE(PLTReports.ITEMID,'CV','PH')
```

Comment: Doing that kind of string manipulation in the join itself is bad for performance.

Comment: If the data are not too complicated, the bad performance will be quite invisible.

Comment: Unless there's a large data set which generally is a safe assumption. Dont make excuses for bad practices

Comment: The bad practice is the different suffix not my answer.

Comment: I disagree - its both, but whatever :)

Comment: I still get an ambiguous column name error from this method

Comment: Yeah the different suffix is ridiculous, but that's the creator's legacy issue I'm trying to work around here.

Comment: Also, each table has a different number of rows. Fun

Comment: Laserwolf :  edit your question with the exact error.

@DougCoats https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729365/tsql-using-replace-function-in-select-with-join Do you have benchmark to be sure that a subquery join will have better performance than the replace in Join ?

Comment: @DanielE.I have included the error in the question edit.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would need to use `REPLACE` in the join condition. Also, fields having the same name need to be prefixed :

```
SELECT 
    PRODUCTION_ALL.* 
    CAST (PLTReports.ENDDATE AS DATETIME) AS ENDDATE 
FROM PLTReports 
INNER JOIN PRODUCTION_ALL ON PRODUCTION_ALL.ITEMID = REPLACE (PLTReports.ITEMID,'CV','PH')
```

Comment: I tried this way, and it only returns the two columns that I would get from the first table alone.

Comment: @Laserwolf : which other columns would you like to get ? Basically you just have to add them to the SELECT clause.

Comment: Most of the data that I want is in the PRODUCTION_ALL table. Only one column of data is in the PLTReports table besides the key

Comment: @Laserwolf : I edited my answer to select all columns of PRODUCTION_ALL (PRODUCTION_ALL.* means all columns in PRODUCTION_ALL). This is just an example to demonstrate that any column can be SELECTed. You might want to adapt this with the list of columns that you actually want to display.

Answer (score 0):

since both tables have an 'ITEMID' you need to specify which should be used by REPLACE():

```
REPLACE (PLTReports.ITEMID,'CV','PH') AS ITEMID,
```

But I think from what you're saying you also have to adjust `PRODUCTION_ALL.ITEMID = PLTReports.ITEMID` because as you say,

> The second table has the same key record but with a different suffix

So you'd need to replace in the join condition, too:

PRODUCTION_ALL.ITEMID = REPLACE(PLTReports.ITEMID,'CV','PH')

This is regrettably inefficient as a temporary unindexed result set from the REPLACE will have to be generated; that's why it's rather unfortunate that your indexes don't match.

Answer (score -1):

Without too much input from you I think this is what youre after

```
SELECT
    x.ITEMID
    , x.ENDDATE
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            REPLACE (ITEMID,'CV','PH') AS ITEMID, 
            CAST (ENDDATE AS DATETIME) AS ENDDATE 
        FROM PLTReports 
    ) x 
INNER JOIN PRODUCTION_ALL ON PRODUCTION_ALL.ITEMID = x.ITEMID
```

you could also do it this way which is probably infinitely better

```
; with cte AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            REPLACE (ITEMID,'CV','PH') AS ITEMID, 
            CAST (ENDDATE AS DATETIME) AS ENDDATE 
        FROM PLTReports 
    )
SELECT 
    cte.ITEMID
    , ENNDATE
    , PRODUCTION_ALL.*
FROM cte 
    INNER JOIN PRODUCTION_ALL ON cte.ITEMID = PRODUCTION_ALL.ITEMID
```

Comment: Why the subquery?

Comment: @DanFarrel well its better than doing that in the join itself which is a bad practice to be in. But there are a few differents ways to get to that point

Comment: Honestly if we were really concerned about performance you wouldn't use a sub query at all and the do the string manipulation in a CTE and then join off of that. I mean it really depends on how much typing you want to do or how complicated you want to get.

Comment: @Laserwolf on the outer select, ITEMID needs to be fully qualified. I omitted that, my bad. Just preface it with the correct table name

Comment: Thanks @DougCoats, the modified syntax works, but I'm still only getting the two columns from cte. It doesn't return any of the data that I'd like to join from the PRODUCTION_ALL table.

Comment: @Laserwolf Then add those columns? you would add those columns in the select in the outer part

Comment: @DougCoats Could you perhaps modify your original answer to show where I would add the columns? The PLTReports table only includes one column of data that I want, as well as the key record. The Production_All table has all of the rest of it. Sorry, my SQL-fu isn't as strong as it probably should be.

Comment: @Laserwolf there that should do it. I didnt realize how new you were to this and made assumptions, sorry. Also, you never said which additional columns you need, so it was kind of difficult to ascertain without that input form you

Comment: IT WOOOOOOORKS!!!!! I don't fully grok how the syntax of adding PRODUCTION_ALL.* lets it get added, but whatever, it works!!!!!!!!!!!

THANK YOU @DougCoats you are a prince.

There's probably a less expensive way to go about this, but I'm totally fine with it as is.

Comment: @laserwolf asterisks in select tend to return the entire table. In this specific example, it return all of PRODUCTION_ALL. If this worked for you please remember to upvote/mark as answered.. I think based off of your comments a good sql tutorial will do you a world of good as well :)

Comment: Totally fair encouragement. Yes, I seldom use SQL this deep. Once I have the tables, I generally use client tools to build analytics and trends. I get how the asterisk works, it's the location of selecting from production_all within the statement that I didn't get. Thanks again.